# How to make CN1Lib that depends on other CN1Lib

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to create a CN1Lib from Steve's cloudinary source, it uses `BouncyCastleCN1Lib.cn1lib`.

How do I use this lib in my code?

When I clean build, I got errors pointing to `javabc.SecureRandom` and `org.bouncycastle.crypto`, even though I have the CN1Lib inside my lib folder and there's no way to do **refresh libs** as all codenameone options are disabled because I don't have the `CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar for the taskdef.

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest cn1libs. If you need to use classes from one cn1lib in another you need to specify that as a requirement to your users and change the classpath of the project to compile against the other cn1lib.

Then in the final project both cn1libs should be placed in the lib directory for the project to work.